# Android fragments - findFragmentByTag always returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I've had a look around and found a couple of questions with a similar topic, but nothing that helped in my case.
I'm trying to access an existing active fragment using **getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG)**, but it always returns **null**. Replies on similar questions suggested that it takes a while for the commit to be executed, so calling findFragmentByTag would return null if called too early. I've tried two things:

- add **getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()**
  immediately after the commit, but still get **null**.
- added a button... pressing this after the activity has been created,
  the fragment registered and the view displayed should leave    the
  system enough time to commit. But i still get **null**.

Here's my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String F_SETTINGS = "f_settings";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            debug();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FSettings newFragment = new FSettings();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(F_SETTINGS);
        ft.commit();
        // getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        //// Activating this did not make any difference...
    }

    debug();
}

private void debug() {
    String txt = "null";
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(F_SETTINGS);
    if (frag != null) {
        txt = frag.toString();
    }
    Log.i("Testing", txt);
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong here?
Cheers,
Max

Comment: are you sure savedInstanceState is null ?

Comment: ft.addToBackStack(F_SETTINGS);  <--- this doesn't tag your fragments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your code you haven't mentioned tag in replace method So,
Use this structure of replace method of fragment

```
ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment,"fragment_tag_String");
```

Refer this link for more information. [fragment replace with tag name](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Oh dear, you wouldn't believe how long I stared at the code to figure whats wrong... thanks, works now.

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Comment: Thank you so much bro.